# Calling PL/SQL procedures from Java

Tags: java, plsql

I am writing a Web Service (WS) interface in Java for an application written in PL/SQL. It has a interface package, which I am trying to convert to WS based calls. Now, a lot of procedures in it look like:

```
procedure mod_add_file (
 p_file     in out mod_documents_01.rec_file,
 p_new_id      out mod$d_documents.document_id_int%type,
 p_new_ver     out mod$d_documents.document_version_int%type,
 p_flag     in out varchar2,
 p_errors   in out varchar2 );
```

Where mod_documents_01.rec_file is a record and mod$d_documents.document_id_int (NUMBER) and mod$d_documents.document_version_int (NUMBER) are columns in a table.

```
type rec_file is record (
 id                        mod$d_documents_content.id%type,
 document_id               mod$d_documents.document_id_int%type,
 document_version          mod$d_documents.document_version_int%type,
 name                      mod$d_documents_content.name%type
  ) ;
```

I have written a library for generating proper PLSQL code for the java connection.prepareCall. For this example it generates following code (I added new lines for readability purpose, normally all is in a one line):

```
declare 
p_new_id mod$d_documents.document_id_int%type;
modInterfaceFile mod_documents_01.rec_file; 
p_new_ver mod$d_documents.document_version_int%type; 

begin 
p_new_id := ?;
modInterfaceFile.id := ?;
modInterfaceFile.document_id := ?;
modInterfaceFile.document_version := ?;
p_new_ver := ?;
MOD_INTERFACE.mod_add_file( modInterfaceFile ?  ? p_new_id p_new_ver ?  ? );
? := p_new_id;
? := modInterfaceFile.id;
? := modInterfaceFile.document_id;
? := modInterfaceFile.document_version;
? := modInterfaceFile.name;  
? := p_new_ver;  
end;
```

First of all, my question is, is this approach any good or is there any better way? I am mostly concerned with a way of passing records and table column types arguments to the procedures.

Also this code generates an error, when trying to execute it:

```
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "" when expecting one of the following
```

The error indicates that the problem occurs at:

```
MOD_INTERFACE.mod_add_file( modInterfaceFile ?  ? p_new_*HERE*id p_new_ver ?  ? );
```

I had a similar errors previously but solved them by removing line breaks. However, now I have no special characters, just whitespace, and such has me stumped.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: what is `MOD_INTERFACE.mod_add_file( modInterfaceFile ?  ? p_new_id p_new_ver ?  ? );` ?  call package?May be you need `MOD_INTERFACE.mod_add_file( modInterfaceFile, ?,  ?, p_new_id p_new_ver, ?,  ? );`

Comment: Yeah, I figured it like an hour after posting the problem. Stupid me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider using [JPublisher](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b10983/intro.htm)

"JPublisher is a utility, written entirely in Java, that generates Java classes to represent database entities such as SQL objects and PL/SQL packages in your Java client program. It also provides support for publishing from SQL, PL/SQL, or server-side Java to Web services and for enabling invocation of external Web services from inside the database."

Comment: Although the jPublisher that is available in jDeveloper (sorry, I haven't mentioned that I was using it) gave me a whole bunch of troubles for it to get to work (the sqlj file generated would get weird errors after just putting new lines between functions for code clarity), it was the best solution to my problem.